# Access to class properties using switch in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have following class:

```
class Router: NSObject {

 enum Route {
    case auth
    case main
    case news
  }

  private var authNavigationController: UINavigationController?
  private var mainNavigationController: UINavigationController?
  private var newsNavigationController: UINavigationController?

func setInitialVC(){
    let vc = LoginService.initialVC()
    setRootViewControllerWithNavigationControlledEmbeded(route: .auth,
                                                         viewController: vc)
  }

  private func getCurrentNavC(_ route: Route) -> UINavigationController?{
    switch route {
    case .auth:
      return self.authNavigationController
    case .main:
      return self.mainNavigationController
    case .news:
      return self.newsNavigationController
    }
  }

  private func setRootViewControllerWithNavigationControlledEmbeded(route: Route,
                                                                    viewController: UIViewController){
    var navC = getCurrentNavC(route)
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    navC = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: viewController)
    print("auth vc \(authNavigationController)")
    print("navC \(navC)")
    self.window?.rootViewController = navC
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
  }
}
```

When i call

```
setRootViewControllerWithNavigationControlledEmbeded(route: Route, viewController: UIViewController){
```

i suppose that `var navC = getCurrentNavC(route)` will point to my class variable `authNavigationController` but in log i can see following:

```
auth vc nil
navC Optional(<UINavigationController: 0x7fd9ca025000>)
```

I want to get this properties with route but look like my logic not work, why?

When app just launched it call - `setInitialVC()`

Comment: Are you sure that at this point your VC has been initialized and sent through correctly? You might want to add code that shows the calls you make to navigate from one VC to the other

Comment: @AlanS i did update

Comment: are you sure that the vc that is getting created has been initialized correctly

Comment: From your code it looks like authNavigationController has never been given a memory, that's why the value is nil.

Answer (score 0):

**Modify the setRootViewControllerWithNavigationControlledEmbeded function like below and try.**

```
private func setRootViewControllerWithNavigationControlledEmbeded(route: Route,
                                                                    viewController: UIViewController){
    var navC = getCurrentNavC(route)
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    //navC = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: viewController)
    print("auth vc \(authNavigationController)")
    print("navC \(navC)")
    self.window?.rootViewController = navC
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
  }
```